# CPQ Javascript Maps

Tags: javascript, cpq-plugins

I am working with the CPQ Javascript Calculator. I need to update the Quote Line based on the product.

I am versed in APEX more than I am in Javascript however in APEX I could do a SOQL Query that Returns a map. In Javascript I can do a Query that returns results that I can make into a map but in Javascript I can only have 2 parms. I want to store 3 columns in the map.

I feel like the map is a good approach to this because I need to check the Quote Line against 3 columns in the Product Object.

```
 if (lineModels.length) {
var varProdIds = [];
//Might want to do a function here. 
lineModels.forEach(function(line) {
  var varProdId= line.record['SBQQ__Product__c'];
  if (varProdId) {
    varProdIds.push(varProdId);
  }  
})
};
 const UniqueProdList = [...new Set(varProdIds)];

  //Get Unique Product List
 var ProdIdList = "('" + UniqueProdList.join("', '") + "')"

 console.log('ProdIdList' + ProdIdList);
 debugger;

 const ProductMap = new Map();

//Get Products in order to check if they need to check the compatability and return a map 
return conn.query('SELECT Id, Model__c, Compatibility_Check__c FROM 
Product2 WHERE ID ' + ProdIdList)
.then(function(results) {
//Loop through the Results from the Query, if there is results create a key value pair
  if (results.totalSize){
    results.records.forEach(function(record) {
        ProductMap.set(record.Id, record.Model__c, record.Compatibility_Check__c);
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to put 3 columns in your map, you could just add the entire record to the map:

```
ProductMap.set(record.Id, record);
```

Or, rather than use a map, you could just use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the `results.records` when you need to find a particular record in the queried results.

Comment: All of that was fantastic... I was hoping that Javascript had this ability

Comment: Apex doesn't have the ability to add 2 values to a map either.